# MySQL PHP, How to use regEX in mysql while selecting data

Tags: php, mysql, regex, serialization

Please masters,I have the following inputs :

```
<label >Please choose :</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="outil[]" value="TV" />
<input type="checkbox" name="outil[]" value="Lecteur CD" />
```

And I have a table "`MyValues`" as the following :

```
+----+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id |                       value                                           |
+----+--------+------------------------------------------------------------- +
|  1 | a:3:{i:0;s:10:"Lecteur CD";i:1;s:16:"Console de salon";i:2;s:2:"TV";} |
+----+--------+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

The field **value** contains a string that is serialized from the fallowing array :

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(10) "Lecteur CD"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "Console de salon"
  [2]=>
  string(2) "TV"
}
```

Now when the user check the inputs he wants data are sent into the server side, and I need to select **`id`** where the checked inputs exists in the `value` field (that is a serialized value from an array - It would be so easy if I could use the function in_array).

My query looks like:

```
"SELECT id FROM MyValues WHERE value =  '".serialize($_POST['outil'])."' ";
```

But this does not work and it's normal, because the user could check only one input and he must find data.

I'm thinking to use regex in mysql if its possible to check if there is at least the sent data but I have a limited knowledge. Please master could you help to resolve this problem ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What about using an NoSQL db like MongoDb to store this kind of schemeless data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help

```
$var1 = !empty($_POST['outil'][1]) ? $_POST['outil'][1] : '';
$var2 = !empty($_POST['outil'][2]) ? $_POST['outil'][2] : '';

$sql = 'SELECT id FROM MyValues WHERE value REGEXP "' . $var1 . '" OR value REGEXP "' . $var2 . '" ';
```

Comment: This is nice. Thanks Jaspal.

Comment: You are welcome. instead of REGEXP, you could also use LIKE "%%" since we are just doing normal text comparison. It will be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Create another table with your fields as rows, connected to your first table instead of the serialized data. Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `table1` (`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table2` (
    `table1_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
    `data` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY `x` (`table1_id`,`data`)
);
```

Then you can insert your data like this:

```
INSERT INTO table1 VALUES(NULL); --This will get you the latest incremented ID

INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(1,'Lecteur CD'),(1,'Console de salon'),(1,'TV');
```

And you can now select ID on one field alone:

```
SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE data = 'Console de salon';
```

table1 is optional, but it is often easier to use the database internal increment system than to write your own for table2 where you will need a counter to increase the id.

Comment: Thanks for responding Lilleman but I really need the serialized value in the field **value**